# How to use Regex with CategoricalArrays in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I was discovering CategoricalArrays when I realize I couldn't filter this vector with Regex. I looked to the exported functions and I found the unwrap function and it seemed to work. Why shouldn't this work directly? is there another form to work with?

```
using CategoricalArray;DataFrame;
df=DataFrame(x=1:6,
fruit=categorical(vcat(repeat(["banana"],3),repeat(["pineapple"],3))));

df[occursin.(r"ple",df.fruit),:] #you'll get an error
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `unwrap`:

```
julia> using CategoricalArrays, DataFrames

julia> df=DataFrame(x=1:6, fruit=categorical(vcat(repeat(["banana"],3),repeat(["pineapple"],3))))
6×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      fruit
     │ Int64  Cat…
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     1  banana
   2 │     2  banana
   3 │     3  banana
   4 │     4  pineapple
   5 │     5  pineapple
   6 │     6  pineapple

julia> df[occursin.(r"ple", unwrap.(df.fruit)),:]
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x      fruit
     │ Int64  Cat…
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     4  pineapple
   2 │     5  pineapple
   3 │     6  pineapple
```

With CategoricalArrays.jl it is important to understand that the elements of `CategoricalArray` are `CategoricalValue`. These objects "carry over" the categorical nature of the data. If you want to get the underlying raw value you need to use `unwrap`.

Comment: Thank you Bogumil, I found it a little bit annoying, given that my experience have been with R. It is something to take in consideration in this Julia journey: how "type-sensitive" it is. I hope to see your book very soon.

Comment: Type-sensitivity is locally inconvenient but globally a blessing. What I mean by this is that indeed sometimes in quick interactive work you need to write more in comparison to R. However, if projects go larger the fact that Julia strictly checks types saves you a lot of work. Note that in, for example, Python [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) were introduced exactly for this reason.